# Physics2D isn't stopping collisions

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-physics

I've been trying to make it so that when I press a key, the collision turns off for all pairs of players and walls. I know the `Physics2D.IgnoreCollision` code is being run, but the players still can't go through walls.

If it helps, the players have `RigidBody2D` and `BoxCollider2D` components and the walls have `PlatformEffector2D` and `BoxCollider2D` components.

Below is the code inside the update function that I'm trying to use to turn off collision.

```c#
if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.I)) 
{
    foreach (var player in allPlayers) 
    {
        BoxCollider2D playerCollider = player.GetComponent<BoxCollider2D>();
        if (playerCollider != null) 
        {
            foreach (var wall in allWalls) 
            {
                BoxCollider2D wallCollider = player.GetComponent<BoxCollider2D>();
                if (wallCollider != null) 
                {
                    Physics2D.IgnoreCollision (playerCollider, wallCollider, true);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In your `foreach var wall in allWalls` try getting the attached `PlatformEffector2D` and disabling it with `enabled=false;`. also consider caching the results of getComponent where possible - it's a bit of an expensive operation.

Comment: Or if doing it for all players and walls anyway simply deactivate the Colliders of the walls?

Comment: However @Ruzihm what if the walls should **only** be disabled for player objects but continue to register collisions for anything else? OP please specify this clearer.

Comment: Instead of using loops at all you might be better using [`Physics2D.IgnoreLayerCollision`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics2D.IgnoreLayerCollision.html)

Comment: In your question you mention `Rigidbody` but you seem to be using 2D colliders. Might not be the issue but just be careful not to mix up 2D and 3D colliders and rigibodies. It might give you unexpected results.

Comment: Yeah, it might require a little bit of re-engineering layers and such but @derHugo 's recommendation of [`Physics2D.IgnoreLayerCollision`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics2D.IgnoreLayerCollision.html) is probably best if you can put walls on one layer and players on another layer (or multiple layers if necessary).

Comment: `BoxCollider2D wallCollider = player.GetComponent<BoxCollider2D>();`? Are you sure this line is correct?

Comment: @Draco18s oh my gosh lol